# WPF DataTrigger without reverting to previous value when unsatisfied

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

When WPF DataTrigger contditions becomes unsatisfied, the values of the properties that has been changed by the DataTrigger will be restored to their previous states. I am wondering if it is possible to overwrite the DataTrigger behaviour and prevent the restoring?

On my UI I have three controls: A, B and C. C is a TabControl. The behaviour I am looking for is to let control A and B active the selected tab in control C:

- If the KeyboardFocus is within control A, set SelectedIndex to 0 on
  C;
- If the KeyboardFocus is within control B, set SelectedIndex to 1 on C;
- But if KeyboardFocus is not within neither A or B, I want the
  SelectedIndex to stay unchanged. This is important because user can
  also manually click the tab on control C.

**Edit:**
I eventually tried this:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TabControl">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
         Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=MyControl1}" 
         Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedIndex" Duration="0">
                  <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>  

        </DataTrigger>

   <DataTrigger 
        Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=MyControl2}" 
        Value="True">

          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedIndex" Duration="0">
                  <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

        </DataTrigger>                      
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TabControl.Style>
  <TabItem Header="Tab1">...<TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Tab2">...<TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And this is the problem I am facing with this approach:

1. It looks like each StoryBoard can only be triggered once: i can click MyControl1 to activate Tab1, then click MyControl2 to activate Tab2, however if I click any of MyControls again, nothing happens
2. I cannot manually swtich tabs after any StoryBoard is triggered. I got an exception:

   System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
    at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.get_SelectedIndex()
    at System.Windows.Controls.TabControl.UpdateSelectedContent()
    at System.Windows.Controls.TabControl.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `EventTriggers`.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="txtA" Text="Control: A" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtB" Text="Control: B" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TabControl Name="tbC" Grid.Row="2">
            <TabItem Header="1st" Name="ti1"/>
            <TabItem Header="2nd" Name="ti2"/>
            <TabItem Header="3rd" Name="ti3"/>
        </TabControl>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.GotKeyboardFocus" SourceName="txtA">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="Select1">
                    <Storyboard >
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ti1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.IsSelected)">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                        KeyTime="00:00:00"
                        Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.GotKeyboardFocus" SourceName="txtB">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="Select2">
                    <Storyboard >
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ti2"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.IsSelected)">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                        KeyTime="00:00:00"
                        Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> Trigger objects apply changes or actions based on the state of certain
>   properties, while EventTrigger objects start a set of Actions when a
>   specified routed event occurs. Therefore unlike Trigger,
>   EventTrigger has no concept of termination of state, so the action
>   will not be undone once the condition that raised the event is no
>   longer true.

Comment: The problem here is that GotKeyboardFocus will only be raised to the control that "IsKeyboardFocused" (is it?). What I need is something like "GotKeyboardFocusWithin".